# render profile image in another component - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn how to use props in react js with making a comment post, but I can't seem to make the default profile image, from the ProfilePicture component render in the Comment component. Please help (°Ω°)/, thanks in advance.

```
const ProfilePicture = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img
        className="ProfilePicture"
        src={props.image.pfpUrl}
        alt={props.image.name}
        height={100}
        width={100}
        />
    </div>
  )
};

// user's comment
const comment = {
  image: {
    name: "Default Profile Image",
    pfpUrl: 'https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/009/292/244/small/default-avatar-icon-of-social-media-user-vector.jpg'
  }
}

const Comment = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProfilePicture image={comment.pfpUrl}/>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Comment image={comment.image} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a prop called `image` here:

```
<Comment image={comment.image} />
```

But nowhere in the `<Comment>` component do you use that prop.  Instead, you use `comment` directly:

```
<ProfilePicture image={comment.pfpUrl}/>
```

And `comment` has no property called `pfpUrl`.  If you want to use the object directly, use the correct property:

```
<ProfilePicture image={comment.image.pfpUrl}/>
```

(And of course remove the prop since it's unused.)

If you want to use the prop, use the prop:

```
<ProfilePicture image={props.image}/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked and it cleared up my misunderstanding in using props. Okay, so 'comment' doesn't have a property called 'pfpUrl', but 'image' does, that makes much more sense on why I'm supposed to do '{comment.image.pfpUrl}', if I wanted to access the object. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be more careful with props. Typescript would help you a lot to avoid such errors.

```
const ProfilePicture = ({image}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img
        className="ProfilePicture"
        src={image.pfpUrl}
        alt={image.name}
        height={100}
        width={100}
        />
    </div>
  )
};

// user's comment
const comment = {
  image: {
    name: "Default Profile Image",
    pfpUrl: 'https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/009/292/244/small/default-avatar-icon-of-social-media-user-vector.jpg'
  }
}

const Comment = ({image}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ProfilePicture image={image}/>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Comment image={comment.image} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```